# How to Pass more than one data of select option from one page to another without javascript

Tags: jsp, select, dropdown

i have a webpage as a.jsp with following code

```
<form method="post" action="selector.jsp">
    <select name="select" id="dropdown">        
        <Option data-name="a" value="1">a</Option>
        <Option data-name="b"  value="2">b</Option>
        <Option data-name="c"  value="3">c</Option>
         <Option data-name="d"  value="4">d</Option>       
           </select>
    <input type="submit" value="click"> 
  </form>
```

and i have a webpage as b.jsp with following code

```
 <body>   
    <%
       request.getParameter("select");     
       out.println(request.getParameter("select"));
    %>
   </body>
```

I need pass the both "data-name" and "value" of selected option from a.jsp to b.jsp wihtout any script involved

Comment: <select name="select" id="dropdown" multiple>

Comment: use `request.getParameterValues("select")` to get mutliple values in jsp